# Google Maps API add Listeners to an array of markers

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map displaying markers based on a database that are saved in an array. Now I want to add an animation to them. Quick research gave me [information about single markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) yet no hint how I could perform those actions to multiple markers.

Being pretty much new to Javascript, I am not quite sure how to perform this.

I have a php based `foreach` loop, in which the markers are added. (Database requests will only work with php as far as I understand).

I tried inserting

`google.maps.event.addListener(flightMarkers[flightMarkers.length], 'click', flightMarkers[flightMarkers.length].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE););`

but then the map is not even displayed anymore.

Any Ideas and hints are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dr.Molle and @Lukas Kovac this is what works:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < flightMarkers.length; i++) {
              google.maps.event.addListener(flightMarkers[i], 'click',

              function () {
                  this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
              });
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

`flightMarkers.length` contains number of items in flightMarkers.

So when you have

```
flightMarkers = new Array();
flightMarkers[ 0 ] = "value";
flightMarkers[ 1 ] = "value";
flightMarkers[ 2 ] = "value";
```

`flightMarkers.length` will contain number `3`, but the last index in that array is `2`. And when you type `flightMarkers[flightMarkers.length]` in this example it will be `flightMarkers[3]`, which is undefined.

If you want to add listener only to last marker, use `flightMarkers[flightMarkers.length - 1]`.
If you want to add listener to every marker, use for loop:

```
for( var i = 0; i < flightMarkers.length; i++ ) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(flightMarkers[i], 'click', 
    flightMarkers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE););
}
```

Comment: Good point about the -1, don't know why I didn't think of that myself. 
Unfortunately neither of the two solution you posted works. Both still just "delete" the map from the website. I made sure to put the code in the javascript part... But I am starting to get the feeling that it doesn't like the ´.addListener´ or something like that.
Google Maps Version is 3.18.14 btw. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about wrapping last argument into function(){}?

`for( var i = 0; i < flightMarkers.length; i++ ) {
    google.maps.event.addListener( flightMarkers[i], 'click', function() {
        flightMarkers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    });
};`

Comment: Getting closer ;) Now the map is displayed, with all markers, but the animation is missing, and if you inspect the map (using chrome) you get the following error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAnimation' of undefined
If you want to check it out yourself: http://wdwva.com/index.php/routemap

Comment: @Dr.Molle doesn't work unfortunately :( Just doesnt display a map any more if I add that anywhere in the code